# Laravel 5 One to Many relation issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `company` table and an `attributes` table with all sorts of value in it.

One company `hasMany` attributes and an attribute `belongsTo` a company.

Now I have a value inside the attributes table with a 'account_nr_start' *(for example, when a new user is added to a company its account_id starts counting up from 1000)*

Attribute Table:
[image: attributes table]

Models:

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'attributes';

    protected $fillable = ['attribute', 'value'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
}


class Company extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'companies';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'id');
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Attribute');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function edit(Company $company, CompaniesController $companies)
{
    $companies = $companies->getCompaniesName(Auth::user()->company_id);


    $account_nr_start = $this->company->attributes()
        ->where('attribute', '=', 'account_nr_start')
        ->get();

    dd($account_nr_start);

    return view('company.edit', ['company' => $company, 'id' => 'edit','companies' => $companies]);
}
```

If I `dd($account_nr_start)` I'll get an empty collection `Collection {#318 ▼ #items: [] }`

While it needs to show

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing the whole context, I'd guess that in your controller `$this->company->attributes()` should actually be `$company->attributes()` if you want to use the company you just passed in, no? Otherwise, make sure that `$this->company` is persisted, i.e. that `$this->company->id` is not `null`.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks. I'm not sure why $this->company doesn't work then?

Comment: I can't tell, as I said, I don't know the whole context. Maybe you *do* want to use `$this->company` and not the one you passed to the function. Either way, make sure the `$company`-object you're using is not just a newed up instance but has also been persisted to the database and has an `id`. Maybe the instance passed in through the constructor is different from the one passed directly to the function.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Hope the following will work.</del> See the edit.

```
Company::with(['attributes' => function($query) {
    $query->where('attribute', '=', 'account_nr_start');
}])->findOrFail(Auth::user()->company_id);
```

EDIT: I misunderstood the question previously. You wanted the attributes. Try the following instead.

```
Attribute::whereHas('company', function($query) 
{
    $query->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->company_id);
})->where('attribute', '=', 'account_nr_start')->get();
```